# what is the module of 'BrowserAnimationsModule' in newst angular?

Tags: angular

in the past , I use below code in my angular project :

```
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
```

but now , when I want use the **BrowserAnimationsModule** , I get this error :

> Cannot find  @angular/platform-browser/animations module

what can I do ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43058589/augular-2-router-animation-cannot-find-module-angular-platform-browser-anima

Answer (score 0):

Try installing angular/animations again with :

> npm install --save @angular/animations